# NHibernate - Updating a table with a trigger on it causes an error - Unexpected row count: 2; expected: 1

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

So I'm trying to update an object in my MS SQL 2005 database using NHibernate.  Please keep in mind that this is a legacy database used in many live systems and I can't remove the triggers.

When my data provider tries to .SaveOrUpdate() a row I get two returns (one for the actual update, and one when the trigger executes)

The raw return looks like this:

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

NHibernate then throws an exception like this:  "Unexpected row count: 2; expected: 1"

I'm essentially looking an equivalent to "SET NOCOUNT ON" from within the session.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

And you can't update the trigger to disable/enable the SET NOCOUNT before/after the trigger's code ?

SET NOCOUNT ON 
-- your trigger
SET NOCOUNT OFF

Comment: It's so rare to just get the answer quickly and easily. Thanks Matthieu.

Comment: You rock my world! Thank you so much - Exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: Best answer ever! Thanks Matt you're a Rockstar!

Comment: You are a genius, spent an hour wondering why it wasnt working

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate JIRA [NH-1353](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1353) provides a patch to deactive row count checking in the config file. It appears that this patch hasn't made it into the 2.x trunk.